# Justify this equation?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\dfrac{e^{i\theta} -1}{e^{2i\theta} -1} = \dfrac{e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} - e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}}{e^{\frac{3i\theta}{2}}-e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}} $$

However:

$$e^{\frac{i\theta}{2} - e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}} = 2i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \text{ - by Euler}$$

So:

$$e^{i\theta} -1 = 2i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) $$

$$e^{i\theta} = 2i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+ 1 $$

$$\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) = 2i\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+ 1 $$

Which clearly isn't right...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Multiply by 1, $$\frac{e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}}{e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

$e^{i\theta} - 1 = 2i \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ is wrong.

Instead it should be $e^{i\theta} - 1 = 2i e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$.

In fact to justify the equation, we just multiply $e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}$ on both the numerator and denominator of the R.H.S.

$$e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} (e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} - e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}) = e^{i\theta} - 1$$
$$e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}} (e^{\frac{3i\theta}{2}} - e^{\frac{-i\theta}{2}}) = e^{2i\theta} - 1$$

Comment: Ahhh! Silly me.
Thank you